# "No DNS domain configured" when I join AD domain

Tags: samba, dns, active-directory

I have an issue to join Active Directory with my DNS. Someone can help me with this issue. I checked my `/etc/hosts`file and everything is fine.

```
root@terminal:~# sudo net ads join -k
```

Result:

```
Using short domain name -- COPICOM
Joined 'TERMINAL' to dns domain 'copicom.local'
No DNS domain configured for terminal. Unable to perform DNS Update.
DNS update failed: NT_STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER


root@terminal:~# net ads join
```

Result:

```
Failed to join domain: failed to lookup DC info for domain 'COPICOM.LOCAL' over rpc: The attempted logon is invalid. This is either due to a bad username or authentication information.
```

Content of **/etc/hosts** :

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   fileserver
10.128.35.2     copserv.copicom.local   copserv
```

Thanks for support.